# Flutter: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Range is empty

Tags: sql, flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

My app is working fine, but anyway I got this error.

I'm using a future builder to read from database and display on screen the data, not the list but 1st item, and if i do some actions the counter which is 0 by default is increasing and getting me next data Item. (I think that I'm searching items by Index in the list that is empty and thats why I get the error but Im not sure).

The problem is that Ive seen on internet only fixes to LisView.Builder but Im not using one, and I have no idea why Im getting this error.

[image]

Next page after I enter Barcode in textField (this is first data from list)

[image]

List of items

[image]

```js
// declaration of counting variable
var index = 0;

// function to read from db
 Future<List?> read(String query) async {
    var result = await SqlConn.readData(query);
    query.replaceAll("\"", "");
    List _list = jsonDecode(result) as List;
    debugPrint('${_list.length} <===== size');
    return _list;
  }

// part of code that display data
child: FutureBuilder<List?>(
                    future: read(
                        // "SELECT ProductSeriesDescr FROM ScanRest WHERE ProductStation = '${widget.nrStatie}' AND BoxID = '$cutieScan' and ProductSeriesDescr != '0331120' ANd ProductSeriesDescr != '020322'"),
                        "SELECT ProductAdress, replace(ProductName, '\"', '')ProductName, NeedCount, ScanCount, ProductBarCode, ProductSeriesCount, ProductExpirationDate FROM ScanRest WHERE ProductStation = '${widget.nrStatie}' AND BoxID = '$cutieScan' Order By ProductName ASC"),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                        case ConnectionState.waiting:
                          return const Text('Loading....');
                        default:
                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            debugPrint(
                                "call error"); //"call error = ${snapshot.error}"
                            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                          } else {
                            debugPrint(
                                "call success"); // "call success = ${snapshot.data}"
                            List data = snapshot.data ?? [];
                            return Column(children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  // ----------------------------------- Product Adress
                                  Expanded(
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        i++;
                                        if (i == snapshot.data!.length) {
                                          i = 0;
                                        }
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                        height: 60,
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Text( 'i=' +i.toString() + " " + ((data[i] as Map)['ProductAdress'].toString()),
                                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                          ),
                                        )),
                                  )),

                                  // ------------------------------------ NEED COUNT
                                  Expanded(
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      _nrProdusController.text =
                                          (data[i] as Map)['NeedCount'].toString();
                                    },
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      height: 60,
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          ((data[i] as Map)['NeedCount']
                                              .toString()),
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)]),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )),
                                ],
                              ),
```

Data displayed in Read function

Data displayed when trying to display on screen

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List data = snapshot.data ?? [];

// Simple fix that worked for me:

if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {

```
return Text('Waiting for BarCode');
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are using an empty list if the snapshot has no data. Indexing into the list causes the error.

Better to check `snapShot.hasData` and show some other widget when it returns false.

Comment: I would like to get some tips of treating this error, If any additional information is needed I can show and give (for my code)

Comment: @DimaC You have `List data = snapshot.data ?? [];` so when the snapshot has no data, your list is empty, and your code does not seem to handle that. It is a common case the the snapshot has not data, e.g. when the build function is called the first time.